# How do I create a container with more than four corners (with border radius) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[image: The desired widget]

I want to create this widget. Can anyone help with proper code?

Comment: try OutlinBorder/ShapeBorder

Comment: use [roundPolygon](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L24) function - there is o lot of examples provided

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ClipPath widget also you can change it accoding to your requirements

```
class MyCustomShape extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: _MyCustomShapeClipper(),
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyCustomShapeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final radius = 20.0;

    // Top-left rounded corner
    path.moveTo(radius, 0);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius));

    // Top edge
    path.lineTo(size.width - radius, 0);

    // Top-right rounded corner
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius));

    // Dent in top-right corner
    path.lineTo(size.width, radius + 40);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 40, radius);

    // Right edge
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - radius);

    // Bottom-right rounded corner
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, size.height), radius: Radius.circular(radius));

    // Bottom edge
    path.lineTo(radius, size.height);

    // Bottom-left rounded corner
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, size.height - radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius));

    // Left edge
    path.lineTo(0, radius);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: this code isn't giving the expected output. I tried it on the following [dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=43a951f7d380a3d875ec355da46f711e)